# MvvmCross Android Bindings with dependent assembly

Tags: android, mvvmcross

Our main android app includes MvxBindingAttributes.xml to provide binding syntax to the android axml.
The issue I've run into, is when writing a plugin (dependent android assembly) which also has xaml definitions (the assembly has it's own MvxBindingAttributes.xml defined as a resource)

Now when compiling the app, compile errors moan that there are duplicate definitions for binding attributes.
Is there guidance on what pattern to follow to allow binding attributes to be used in the main app as well as the referenced android plugin code?

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out the same resource cannot be defined in dependent assemblies, so the solution (for me) was to define a shared android assembly that contains common concerns (such as the MvxBindingsResource) which both the android app and android plugin assembly can reference.